# How to populate search form with search term in View / Panels / Page?

Tags: 7, search, views

I've using Views and Page Manager to create a custom search results page. You can see it here:

http://quotefail.com/search/node/world

The page is being generated by Page Manager. I've got a Search Form in the top panel, but it starts empty. I'd like it to be pre-filled with the search term that was used to generate this page.

How can I prepopulate the search form with that search term?

Here is my page config:

[image]

Here is my Search View in the center panel:

[image]

Comment: Upvote for relevant screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like from that link that the search form is the search block form, so you can do this as a theme form alter (you could also make a custom module in a similar fashion with form alters but this should serve your needs).  This goes in your template.php for your theme:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'search_block_form':
      //checking if arg(2) exists so it doesn't try to do this if some visits the search page straight away
      if(arg(2)){ 
        $form['search_block_form']['#default_value'] = arg(2);
      }
      break; 
  }
}
```